# Enable systemd service in yocto build

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

I know how to create a systemd service and also how to run and enable it etc. on a running system, but I would like to know how I can make one enabled by default on a yocto image. In other words, I want to have a custom service enabled on a image the first time the image is run, i.e. after flashing it. How does one go about implementing this?

EDIT:
I already have systemd and do not need installation instructions for it. I need a way to register a service with it during the build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just create a symlink of the service in `/etc/systemd/system/yourTarget.wants`?

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity, but how would one do that with yocto?

Comment: Here is a BitBake recipe, that creates symlinks.  Does that help?    https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Cookbook:Appliance:Startup_Scripts

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't add a new answer, as this question is currently on hold. Sure, you can manually create the link as you're told in this answer. Though, the better way would be to use the `systemd.bbclass`. You'd do this by `inherit systemd` in your recipe, and then specify the name of the service file in `SYSTEMD_SERVICE = "name_of_the_file"`. This will automatically enable the service for you.